# Appending php code in <div> using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to create a dropdown calendar in our capstone project. I try ajax in dropdown bootstrap 4 but it doesn't collapse. So I want to try the include method. Please help.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#btnClick").click(function() {
         $("#container").html("<?php include('something.php'); ?>");
     });
 });
```

**something.php//**

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>Yeah!</p>
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='script.js'></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
<button id="btnClick">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: use ajax for this

Comment: But the dropdown of bootstrap-4 doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try load instead of html

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#btnClick").click(function() {
         $("#container").load("<?php include('something.php'); ?>");
     });
 });
```